# Geodesics on a minimal surface are Torsionless?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

For any smooth continuous surface it is known that ***only*** lines of curvature $ (\psi=0, \pm \pi/2, \pi...) $ have zero geodesic torsion, ( time being keeping aside great circles on a sphere) :

$$\tau_g= (\kappa_1- \kappa_2) \sin \psi \cos\psi $$

For a minimal surface  we have $$\kappa_1<0,\,2 H =(\kappa_1+ \kappa_2)=0, \,   \tau_g = H\, \sin 2 \psi =0 $$

So ***on a minimal surface all geodesics have zero Torsion***, a result extremely easy to establish.

*For torsion*

$$\tau_g= (\kappa_1- \kappa_2) \sin \psi \cos\psi \rightarrow (-\kappa_1- \kappa_2) \sin \psi \cos\psi, $$

and likewise when the latter vanishes we have two real possibilities for 
*Torsion-free geodesics on minimal surfaces*:

**$$ H=0 ,\tau_g=0, \kappa_g=0 $$**

*Since $H$ is a factor of $\tau_g$ both vanish together.*

Torsionless geodesics on a catenoid of revolution:

[image: CatnGeodTorsnZero]

Is this statement true ***in general***? If so, what are Differential Geometry textbook references? If not, what could be conceptually incorrect in this context?

Thanks for your comments or answers.

They are indeed not torsionless. However, not deleting background of this, what appears to be a pitfall.

*For normal curvature*

We have all possible curvatures $(\kappa_n, \tau_g) $ positive and negative combinations nicely depicted on a Mohr's circle scalar diagram applicable for either positive or negative signs of Gaussian curvature $ K=\kappa_1  \kappa_2$.

$$ \kappa_n= (\kappa_1\cos^2\psi  +  \kappa_2\sin ^2\psi ) \rightarrow (-\kappa_1 \cos^2\psi  +  \kappa_2\sin ^2\psi) ,$$

When the latter vanishes we have two real directions of asymptotes defined by $ \psi_{1,2}= \tan^{-1}\sqrt{\kappa_1/\kappa_2}$.The parameter lines are either parallel or perpendicular to arc for principal directions of curvature, defined by this angle.

So changing sign of $\kappa_1$ in this manner is a valid.

In addition, these are valid for $\tau$ depiction in bi-polar coordinate representations relevant to curvature. [iso-$\tau$ bipolar coord patches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipolar_coordinates)

Representation of  $(\kappa_n, \tau_g ) $ for negative Gauss curvature is sketched below using Mohr's circles of curvature.

[H=0 & geodesics](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.em/1048516035) seems to discuss the topic but not clear where it is of  direct relevance.

EDIT1:

[image: K>0 & K<0 Mohr Circles]

In this discussion about sign of curvature,combination of geodesics and new a scalar curvature $ \kappa_{n Meta} $ I am defining as:

$$ \kappa_{n Meta} = -\kappa_1 \cos^2 \psi + \kappa_2 \sin^2 \psi $$
result in revolved cusped surface *Barrels* ( different initial conditions)  imaged below.They have an important common invariant $ a^2= K\cdot r^4$ whose significance is not yet clear to me.

[image: knMeta_Geods_SOR]

Comment: You made a sign mistake (who didn't do it at least once?). In the formula for the geodesic torsion we have the **difference** of principal curvatures, and in the mean curvature their **sum**.

Comment: Suggestion: it is really hard to figure out what exactly is your question here. You ask "Is this statement true in general?" But I am entirely unsure to which statement you  refer. And how general is general? Are you looking for statements about curves in (minimal) submanifolds of a manifold?

Comment: Statement put in bold face. For minimal surfaces at least in R^3 whether geodesics have no torsion?

Comment: Seems to me that even on the catenoid, most geodesics have torsion. Think about taking the circular geodesic about the neck and peturbing the starting direction a small amount - the resulting geodesic should look locally like a helix.

Comment: Thanks, fully agree with your comment. Shall later re-edit my post after reconciling two things 1) curvature convention of axes in program and role of half difference curvature which I strongly feel should be a recognized entity in its own right. Regards

Comment: @IvanIzmestiev I agree with the error of sign, and shall later on explain circumstances of my error commission.. foremost  that since curvature is sign sensitive, a need arises to recognize "mean" $HD= \kappa_1-\kappa_2$ and a new "normal" $ \kappa_{meta} = \kappa_1 \cos^2 \psi - \kappa_2 \sin^2 \psi$ as new scalars of curvature needing  separate definitions on their own. Regards

Comment: Yes, principal curvatures change the sign if you take the opposite unit normal. But they do this simultaneously.